What does statically casting enumerator T to std::underlying_type<T> actually do?
I'm learning about modern c++ and I am currently reading about template and auto type-deduction.
As a challenge I tried to write a function from a book to solve a problem, and it ended up differing very slightly to what the book suggested.
Exercise:
Write a template function that returns an integral value of an enum.
My function:
template<typename T>
constexpr auto EnumToIntegral(T enumerator) noexcept
{
    return std::underlying_type_t<T>(enumerator);
}

Book's function:
template<typename T>
constexpr auto EnumToIntegral(T enumerator) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(enumerator);
}

The only difference here is the static_cast, which I cannot figure out the point of.
Both functions compile and run as expected.
Looking at other snippets from posts regarding getting integral enum-values I also see static_cast being used, but I've failed to find any reasoning for this.
I have tried both with, and without the static_cast, but I get the same result.
The enum values are of type int, and the function that is using this result is std::get.

Some people prefer static_cast rather than the big hammer "omni cast" (C style cast — even though you are using the "function style" cast, it's still a C style cast).

OT: standard solution is std::to_underlying if you have C++23

The first (your version) is a C style cast. The old one which is not "advised" to be used in C++. You're basically doing (int)MyEnum which converts the enumerator constant to its int value. The second, using static_cast does a "proper" casting from the enumerator constant to int.

Thank you, that makes sense!
Do I answer my own question to close this?

@HoraceNess While not the actual situation of your question, because primitives are "simple" (and you could prolly get away with a C-style cast), if you do want to read up on the actual differences in practice involving object type casting, here's some night reading material: When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast, and reinterpret_cast be used? and Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast . This might expand your views on each situation for use when you'll need them, depending on the scenario.

The main thing it does is that it changes the type of the expression to std::underlying_type<T> ;-). if you ask "what does it do that the C style cast doesn't do" then the answer is "nothing". The C style cast is a static cast here.

The fundamental casts in C++ are static_cast, const_cast, reinterpret_cast and dynamic_cast.
Each of these are able to cast expressions of certain types and value categories to certain other types. The sets of conversions permitted by each of them is different and sometimes they overlap with different semantics.
There is also the explicit type conversion (in cast notation), better known as "C-style cast" for the syntax form derived from C, in the language. With one minor exception, is however just an combination of the previously mentioned casts.
Such a cast expression will do the first sequence of casts that is possible out of the following list:

const_cast
static_cast
static_cast followed by const_cast
reinterpret_cast
reinterpret_cast followed by const_cast

Additionally this cast expression permits the static_cast in this choice to ignore accessibility of base classes, i.e. it can convert a derived class pointer to a private base class pointer which no other construct in the language allows.
So, C-style casts are dangerous because they can cast almost everything to everything else with difficulty to be sure of the semantics and to avoid mistakes.
The problem is now that there are two different syntax forms for explicit type conversion which share these semantics of C-style casts:

(T)e (cast notation, aka "C-style cast")
T(e) (functional notation)

where T is the target type and e the source expression. The first form is generally known because it is the syntax C uses. However, the second one, which is specific to C++, still has the exact same explicit type conversion semantics of the C-style cast, but is confusing because it looks similar to

T(e1, e2)
T()
T{e}

where e1 and e2 are again expressions. While formally still explicit type conversion expressions, these do not perform a cast sequence as mentioned above but instead obtain a result via direct-initialization of an imagined variable declaration of the same form. Only if a single expression is used in parentheses, not braces, it is an explicit type conversion with the powers mentioned above.
So, if one wants to be consistent about avoiding C-style casts, one should also avoid expressions of the form T(e).
But that is what you are using. static_cast is more explicit, stating what fundamental cast you want, not that the compiler should attempt the list mentioned above and potentially make a wrong choice.
In this particular example there is no difference, because an expression with enumeration type can always be cast to its underlying type with a static_cast, so that the second entry in the list is guaranteed to be chosen. But that may not be obvious.
Actually, the form T{e} (direct-list-initialization) is, typically, even weaker than static_cast, while still stronger than an implicit conversion. But it wouldn't suffice here because it doesn't allow the conversion for scoped enumeration types.
(Except for initialization with braces, none of this has anything to do with modern C++ features btw. These rules have been present since the first C++ standard C++98.)

C-style casts are not so much an abstraction as a muddling of the more specific casts.

@Spencer Yes, that wasn't the right choice of words.

T(e) isn't a C-style cast, if that's what you are suggesting. Functional style casts don't exist in C. Edit: I read it a bit more carefully and I don't think you suggest that, but it's not 100% clear.

@TedLyngmo No, it is. That's just not well-known it seems (for understandable reasons as I mentioned in my answer): https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#2.sentence-1 For example using T = int&; float x = 0; int& y = T(x); will compile and cause UB when using y because that's a reinterpret_cast. It is normally not that bad, because the functional notation doesn't allow compound type specifiers directly in the syntax.

@TedLyngmo I am not saying that it exists in C btw. I am using "C-style cast" to refer to the semantics of "explicit type conversion" as the standard calls it. I guess one could also interpret "C-style cast" as the specific syntax form used in C, rather than the semantics behind it in C++.

Yeah, got it. It's equivalent to a C-style cast so perhaps one could call it a C-style cast equivalent or similar to not give the impression that the cast actually works in C.
